# Shortcut for "Keep Open"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In visual studio I often open files using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and hitting enter on the file I desire.

To keep this file open even when navigating to another file, you can click on the "Keep Open" button on the file tab. This is slightly cumbersome... Is there anyway to do this with a shortcut instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a shortcut to the **Window.KeepTabOpen** command.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>

When I right click on the file tab, I can see this shortcut listed to the right of "Keep Tab Open"